# Using Post-Thumbnails on Wordpress frontpage as links to categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want my Wordpress frontpage to show post thumbnails but when you click on them, you don't open a blog post but a category. So that a post thumbnail features as a preview to a categorie, where all the posts belonging to this category are shown.

I thought about categorizing some posts as 'categories-thumbnails' and then I'll hide everything else on the frontpage apart from the posts labeled 'categories'. But how can I link the thumbnail to the actual categories instead of a blogpost?

Or is there another easy way to achieve this look? Should I just use an "overlay" html-non-wordpress-frontpage that shows such a layout and manually link thumbnails or buttons on that html page to the wordpress categories?

Answer (score 1):

It still isn't entirely clear why you would want that, as it seems like this would confuse users who are expecting to go to a specific post.

If you wanted to do that, you would figure out what was generating the photo URLs in the backend, and then change that to pull the URL from the category associated with a specific post, as opposed to the URL for that post. I'd need to know more about the structure of your site to give you more detail.